# PowerBI - Draw Line Chart with X Axis Grouped by Date (in Days), When Column contains Full timestamp?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, linechart

I've been trying to figure this for several hours now.
In my SQL table I have a full timestamp column, with date and time of the action, e.g. last time a user was logged in.

Say I have two users who logged in today so far, in different hours. I want to see "2" log ins for today's Date, instead of seeing them broken down further into exact timestamps.

[See screenshot for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbzUH.png)

What's the easiest way to do this?

EDIT:
Seems like the whole issues stems from my desire to use "Direct Query" method to load the data.

If I'm just importing the whole table (as `users_table (2)`), Then yes, I can create a new column with this syntax:

`Column = 'users_view (2)'[last_active].[Date]`

And plot the graph that I Want.

However, I am unable to create this column on direct query mode. Trying to create this column leads to an error:

> Column reference to 'last_active' in table 'users_view' cannot be used
> with a variation 'Date' because it does not have any.

If such basic functinoally is not possible, then what's the merit of Power BI? my use case is to create a REAL time dashboard.

Seems like if I want to have anything in real time, it means I can't build even the most basic graph, and vice-versa.

So either I'm missing something, or Power BI is worthless for real time reporting.

Comment: Looks like you forgot the screenshot.

Comment: Just added it now, thanks

Comment: I recommend looking into something more suitable for your needs, such as Grafana.

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow these steps:

1. In your fact table, create a new column that corresponds to the *date* of the timestamp (this will be a grouping dimension column for your timestamps)
2. Add a measure that counts rows of your table
3. In a new chart, e.g. line chart, bar chart, whatever - use the *date* column as X-axis information, and the row count measure as your Y-axis information

**Edit:** Since it is now apparent you insist on using Direct Query for this - it would appear your data is not in the correct format to support what you want to do. The solution would be to provide Power BI with the correct format for the analysis you want to do. Like adding a column in your SQL database table.

A very costly way of calculating "something" useful would be to do a cumulative count based on timestamp that resets daily. This will look messy but for a site with a lot of activity it will be able to plot something. But it will be slow - since obviously we are far, far away from what would constitute a "sensible" use-case for Power BI using Direct Query.

```
Cumulative Daily Logins = 
VAR _max_time = MAX ( users_table[last_active] )
VAR _date = DATEVALUE ( _max_time ) 
RETURN
COUNTROWS (
    FILTER ( 
        ALL ( users_table ) ,
        users_table[last_active] <= _max_time 
          && DATEVALUE ( users_table[last_active] ) = _date 
    )
)
```

Comment: I just started using Power BI and have no idea how to do step 1. I tried right-click table name, then choose add column, it tells me format must be `Column = DATE(Year,Month, Day)`, but I have no idea how to match this format to my desired result. I also wonder why this basic functionally needs so much customization in a tool that is supposed to be user friendly :/

Comment: This is basic functionality, but it also requires a basic understanding of Power BI. Perhaps you need to spend some time familiarizing with the tool you are trying to use. I can recommend the free intro courses from SQLBI.

Comment: I feel this is the one thing I can't really figure. don't have time to take a full intro course right now as I need to get this done by tomorrow. Can you please advise how to do correctly follow step 1?

Comment: If it was a requirement to create the date column in DAX, I would read the documentation for DAX and use `DATEVALUE` instead of the `DATE` function, to start. 

Adding an additional date column based on a timestamp column in Power Query is also trivial, and fully supported by "point and click" - it takes about one minute to figure out. 

According to your post you are even using a table from SQL, in which case it should be fairly straightforward to cast your `datetime` column as `date` in your SQL query and use that.

Comment: Please see my edit. issue actually relates to Direct Query.

Comment: My data is in normal timestamp format in SQL. Power BI makes zero sense If I need to add custom columns to my core tables just to plot a graph. I find it hard to believe this tool offers such a poor UX.

Comment: I think you would benefit from understanding what Power BI is, what it should be used for, and how it works. If I want Power BI to make me a pizza, I can't be angry when it doesn't do that, just because I wanted it to make pizza.

Comment: Power BI is described by MS as "Do more with less using an end-to-end BI platform to create a single source of truth, uncover more powerful insights, and translate them into impact." if MS can't really support live data, how can they call it a single source of truth?